# how can I transfer my photos from glaxaxy s4 to pc?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a broken screen and a wireless mouse. Is there another way I can transfer my photos?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any passcode to your phone, attaching the phone to your PC with a USB cable will enable you to transfer the photos to your PC.

Also, if you had set the default storage of photos to the micro SD card then attaching the micro SD card to your PC via a reader will let you transfer the photos back.

Comment: thank you for your response, but unfortunately i do have a passcode and no micro sd card...any other suggestions?

Comment: sorry forgot to tag you